# Removing specific nested lists from a whole list

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list like this in python

```
[['NS1259', 163, 8.38, 268],
 ['NS6969', 88, 15.7, 620],
 ['NS4722', 155, 10.02, 343],
 ['NS3629', 150, 5.4, 530]]
```

I want to create a function to remove any one nested list from the whole list by using the value in the first string. So using N6969 it would end up like this

```
[['NS1259', 163, 8.38, 268],
 ['NS4722', 155, 10.02, 343],
 ['NS3629', 150, 5.4, 530]]
```

Comment: `[x for x in all_lists if x[0] != "N6969"]` would be one approach

Comment: Have you tried the `pop()` method? https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_pop.asp

Comment: I don't know if it's just me but I can't seem to get that to work :[

Comment: Get what to work?

Comment: Yeah tried pop but I may be using it wrong

Comment: You can't pop from a list you're iterating over.

Comment: Your [x for x in all_lists if x[0] != "N6969"]

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get it to work"?

Comment: @Zackamabeal you forgot the `S` in `NS6969`, so there is no matching element to remove ;)

Comment: Ah, whoops, that's on me lol, looks like OP copy-pasted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want a function, here is an example with a list comprehension:

```
def filteritem(iterable, element):
    return [i for i in iterable if i[0] != element]
```

example:

```
l = [['NS1259', 163, 8.38, 268],
     ['NS6969', 88, 15.7, 620],
     ['NS4722', 155, 10.02, 343],
     ['NS3629', 150, 5.4, 530]]

new_list = filteritem(l, 'NS6969') # outputs a new list without the 'NS6969' line
```

You could also use `filter` instead of a comprehension:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[0]!= 'NS6969', l))
```

Comment: `delitem` is a misnomer though, since this is returning a *new* list, and I think you should explain to OP what that means and how it's different.

Comment: true, if you have a suggestion, what about `filteritem`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
big_list = [
    ['NS1259', 163, 8.38, 268],
    ['NS6969', 88, 15.7, 620],
    ['NS4722', 155, 10.02, 343],
    ['NS3629', 150, 5.4, 530]
]
for i in range(len(big_list)-1, -1, -1):
    if big_list[i][0] == 'NS6969':
        del big_list[i]
```

This works from the end to the start, to avoid losing track of your place in the list when you delete an item. If you are sure there will only be one item with this key, then you could iterate forward and add `break` after deleting the item. But in that case you may be better off using a dictionary instead of a list.

Another option would be to create a new list each time:

```
big_list = [x for x in big_list if x[0] != 'NS6969']
```

Comment: Try `if big_list[i][0] in ("NS6969", "NS1259")` and see what happens :)

Comment: Sorry, I had an off-by-one error in the range function. It works fine now as-is, or with `big_list[i][0] in ("NS6969", "NS1259")`.